# $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb Z)$ homework question

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to show that if $G = \langle \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 1 \\
      0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 0 \\
      1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}\rangle \subset \text{SL}(2, \mathbb Z)$, then $-\text{Id} \in G$. So far I have described $G_1 = \langle \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 1 \\
      0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}\rangle$ and $G_2 = \langle \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 0 \\
      1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}\rangle$ and then tried to express $-\text{Id}$ as a composition of elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$ but it didn't work. I'm not even convinced thought that's the right strategy. Maybe there's a more theoretic argument that I'm missing? Can somebody please give me a hint how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Which products did you consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

Well, to begin with:

$$S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&\;\;1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1&0\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ST^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\;\;0&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\left(ST^{-1}\right)^2=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\;\ldots\ldots$$